# Получить чистые виртуальные методы определенные в в базовом классе

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть следующие классы:

```
class A{
  public:
    virtual void pure() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
  public:
    int some_func();
}
```

Как видим оба класса - абстрактные, тобишь имеют чистые виртуальные методы. Проблема в том, что при парсинге `ast` дерева я не могу получить `void pure()` функцию из класса `B` так как он, хоть и имеет такую функцию, но объявлена она в другом (базовом) классе. Как же мне ее все-таки получить не парся при этом заново все дерево (так как это только сдесь всего два класса, а в реальном премере - сотни и даже больше)?

Comment: Ну, проходите по дереву, находите все классы, сохраняете их в каком-нибудь `std::map` или еще где-нибудь. Потом для каждого сохраненного класса проходите по каждому родителю, и собираете из них все чисто виртуальные методы.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так значит кроме как сохранять или парсить заново выхода нет?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нет. Можно только выбрать, как именно сохранять.

Comment: Во первых эта функция не определена,  потому и класс В тоже является абстрактным узловым классом. Что вы хотите получать, неясно. Пока в каком нибудь дочерном классе вы ее не определите, вы не сможете создавать обьект класса, а  "получать" функцию тем более. Или может я вас неправильно понел....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan прошу прощения, функция не "определена", а "объявлена" - опечатался. Ну а что касается создания объектов класса... - об этом вообще речь не идет. В впросе я написал, что используется ast - о каком "создании экземпляров" тут  может идти речь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ не парсить заново один - сохранить результаты исходного парсинга в ином, более подходящем для последующей обработки, формате.

Если вы уже разобрали класс `A`, то логично результаты этого разбора сохранить для дальнейших нужд. В частности для случая наследования от этого класса. При разборе класса `B` дополнительно сослаться на результаты разбора `A`.

Имхо, всё это достаточно очевидно.